# Nested key value pairs in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have this problem in *hadoop*.

I have a list of user activities. Each user can take a different class each day. I want the count of the number of classes each user took for each class.

For examples suppose there are unknown number of classes. `User A` takes `class A` 10 times, `class B` 2 times and `class C` 3 times. I want to have a *dataset* with the count of the number of classes for each class each user takes

I have daily records of each user. For eg

```
Day 1, User A , Class A
Day 1, User A, Class B
Day 1, User B, Class A
Day 2, User A Class C
Day 2, User B Class C
Day 3, User A Class A.
```

I can use a mapper to read these lines line by line, then use the user as key  and the classes as values. But I know only the keys are sorted not values. So I need to make counts for the values as well.

Is there any way to do nested key value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can define your own custom data type instead of using the built-in data types. In the custom data type, include setting both the values you want and override the `compareTo()` method so that Hadoop can internally compare them and sort them. Then your problem should be solved.